# different between LocalStorageModule and localStorageService

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use angular-local-storage in angularjs, but I want to ask whats the different `LocalStorageModule` and `localStorageService` in this API? thanks

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorageModule is a module and LocalStorageService is a service in it i.e an angular recipe. 
In LocalStorageModule There are other  configuration  and providers also which can be used in app depending on requirement (business or tech) e.g LocalStorageServiceProvider can be used to config application wide LocalStorageService properties in config block of app. 
Hope i am clear

Comment: so what is the function of LocalStorageService?